# django pymongo search bar error need guidance / tutorial

Tags: python, django, search, pymongo

i m new to all this, still learning.

Now task for me is to create search bar using mongodb

What i have done so far

- created the mongodb_connection.py to establish connection using pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


def mongosearch(title=""):
    connection = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    db = connection.djangodb
    collection = db.spiderCollection
    title = collection.find()
    for title in titles:
        pprint.pprint()
```

- created view and importing method from mongodb_connection as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .mongodb_connection import mongosearch
from .models import AppModel

# Create your views here.

def search_view(request):

    results = []
    title_term = ""
    search_term = ""
    titles = AppModel.objects.all()

    if 'search' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['search']
        titles = titles.filter(title__icontains=search_term)
        results = mongosearch(title=title_term)
        print(results)

    context={
        'results':results,
        'count':len(results),
        'search_term':search_term,
        'titles':titles
    }

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

- added the models.py

```
from django.db import models

class AppModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "spiderCollection"
```

- then modified the urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

app_name = 'searchapp'
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.search_view, name='search_view'),

]
```

- created html page under apps/templates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!doctype html>
<html>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <form class = "form-inline my-2  my-lg-1">
        <input
                class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
                name = 'search'
                value = "{{request.GET.search}}">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <ul>
            {%for i in titles %}
            <li>
                {{i.titles}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </form>
</nav>

</html>
```

The problem is i m getting the data fetching from mongodb. I think i m pretty close. As soon as i enter values in the search and hit submit , it errors out in the following.

```
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'titles' is not defined
Exception Location: /Users/qasimbutt/PycharmProjects/IntegratedProject/searchui/searchapp/mongodb_connection.py in mongosearch, line 9
```

Can someone assist me, what change can i make in the mongodb_connection.py file to get it rolling? Also please advise if anything is missing here. 
As i need to fetch the data from mongodb and display it under search.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your first function, the line:

```
    for title in titles:
```

references `titles` before it is defined anywhere. You might have meant:

```
    titles = collection.find()
    for title in titles:
```

Comment: Thanks for your observation, i fixed that but when i run it , it throws the following error . Any ideas?
#######
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'
Exception Location: /Users/qasimbutt/PycharmProjects/IntegratedProject/searchui/searchapp/mongodb_connection.py in mongosearch, line 10

Comment: I'm guessing you want `pprint(title)`

Comment: Hey Belly Buster, thanks for that tip.It fixed half of the problem. but really helpful.
i m unable to display the result, Search seems to be working fine now.
but unable to display the results. appreciate it again if u can look at my template file .html

Comment: Suggest you isolate exactly what isn't working and start another question.

Comment: Hi Belly Buster, i made quite progress but still minor GUI problem, i posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135412/django-search-page-throwing-data . thanks in advance, ur the best