# django search page throwing data

Tags: python, django

I am facing bit of difficulty in making search page work.
The problem is my template and view throwing data on search page. And my search button function doesnt works. 
If some one can have a look and advise what i m missing would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

this is how ugly my search page looks 
[image]

- following is my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .mongodb_connection import mongosearch
from .models import AppModel
from django.db.models import Q


# Create your views here.

def search_view(request):

    model = AppModel
    template_name = 'search.html'
    results = []
    title_term = ""
    desc_term = ""
    search_term = ""
    url_term = ""
    titles = AppModel.objects.all()
    url = AppModel.objects.all()

    if 'search' in request.GET:
         search_term = request.GET['search']
         titles = titles.filter(
                 Q(title__icontains=search_term) |
                 Q(desc__icontains=search_term)
         )
         titles = AppModel.objects.all()
         results = mongosearch(title=title_term
                                #,desc = desc_term)
                               )
         print(results)

    context={
        'results':results,
    'search_term':search_term,
        'titles':titles
    }


    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

- following html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!doctype html>
<html>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <form class = "form-inline my-2  my-lg-1" method = "GET">
    <!--action = "{%url 'search_view'%"> -->
        <input
                class="form-control mr-sm-2"
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search"
                name = 'search'
                value = "{{request.GET.search}}">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

    </form>
    <br><br>
    {% if titles %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {%for i in titles %}
                <li class = "list-group-item">
                    {{i.title}}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

</nav>

</html>
```

- mongo_connection

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

def mongosearch(title=""):
    connection = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    db = connection.djangodb
    collection = db.spiderCollection
    titles = collection.find()
    for title in titles:
        pprint(titles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are overwrite filtered queryset with all objects in your view. You need to remove redundant line:

```
     search_term = request.GET['search']
     titles = titles.filter(
             Q(title__icontains=search_term) |
             Q(desc__icontains=search_term)
     )
     titles = AppModel.objects.all()  # remove this line to not overwrite list
     results = mongosearch(title=title_term
                            #,desc = desc_term)
                           )
     print(results)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, 
- no change in the page reloaded , still spit out the entire data set on the page
- however when i search for something now , it reloads the page and entire table vanishes/disappears.
any ideas what else needs tobe done?

Comment: @redbarret sorry have no other ideas. Probably you typed invalid search request? And in DB there are no record meet this filter? What if you add `print(titles)` to the view what do you see?

Comment: yea, i have added pprint(titles) in mongodb_connection.py that i have added above. did you mean that?

Comment: i typed valid data, does my .html file seems correct? I m new to frontend stuff so struggling with it.

Comment: @redbarret html looks good. Should it be `results = mongosearch(title=search_term)` instaed of `results = mongosearch(title=title_term)` in view?

Comment: thanks and appreciate alot for your help. I tried it but it didnt worked . Still same behaviour. It spits out everything on the main page and on result page doesnt display. Although logs says 200 it means it working fine but display is having issues.